# Algebra question : Prove the inequality.

Tags: inequality

> Let $a , b \ \& \ c$ be positive real numbers satisfying : $$\cfrac{a}{1+b+c} + \cfrac{b}{1+c+a} + \cfrac{c}{1+a+b} \ge \cfrac{ab}{1+a+b} + \cfrac{bc}{1+b+c}+ \cfrac{ca}{1+a+c} $$ 
>   **Prove** that : 
>   $$\cfrac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{ab + bc + ca} + a + b + c + 2 \ge 2 \left(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{bc} \right) $$

This is what I've tried yet : [image: Equation]

While, I know that this is not anything like **appreciable** effort. But, I really have tried a lot after this including the logic of all the denominators being positive.

This is the try for the first equation which didn't lead me anywhere. I tried to simplify the second equation also, this is what I got :

[image: Pretty-Equation]

This looked very good to me. But, again my brain is empty with further ideas.

The ideas I have got till now include : $$\bullet \text{Using AM-GM inequality} : $$

[image: Pretty -3]

I don't know what to do further. I thought about this for 1 day and then at each break, an idea came in my mind but all were in vain.

I will appreciate any help regarding this. And if anyone could comment on my ideas and try to explain how to go on from there too (if there is any way) , then it will be great also.

Thanks!

Comment: Gerry Myerson, thanks for editing the tags. Can you please help me in this question?

Answer (score 3):

[image]Using the given inequality
\begin{align*}
& a+b+c-(ab+bc+ca)\ge 0\implies \dfrac{a+b+c}{ab+bc+ca}\ge 1\\
& (a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)\\
\implies & \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca}=\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}+2\\
\implies & (a+b+c)\left(\dfrac{a+b+c}{ab+bc+ca}+1\right)=\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca} +(a+b+c)+2\\
\implies & 2(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca})≤2(a+b+c)≤\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}+(a+b+c)+2
\end{align*}

Comment: The first inequality can be upgraded to strict inequalities, leading to the final inequality upgradable also. Guess the non-strict inequality in the problem statement is rather misleading.

Comment: Can anyone also comment on the methods I tried? Because I think there may be alter methods too for this question.

Comment: @Nilan.C.Manoj : How did you get to $$ a + b + c -(ab + bc + ca) \ge 0 $$

Comment: For any non negative a and b, we have a≥a/(1+b)

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there any proof for this too?

Comment: And Nilan, can you please type the whole thing for how you got to a + b + c - (ab + bc + ca) >= 0 . As, I don't know how the above inequality you typed is connected to the quest.

Comment: I think it is obvious. Am I done anything wrong?

Comment: Try to replace a by a-bc and b by b+c. I think it will work.

Comment: I am not sure whether you have done anything wrong or not. I'm just thinking that how exactly you got to the inequality. $$a + b + c - (ab + bc + ca) \ge 0 $$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15465/discussion-between-kushashwa-ravi-shrimali-and-nilan-c-manoj).

Comment: Please come there. @NilanC.Manoj

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali: move the right side to the left side, you end up with one term that look like $\frac{a-bc}{1+b+c}$. Then $a-bc>\frac{a-bc}{1+b+c}$ since $1+b+c>1$. Do that for all 3 term. Then you will get $a-bc+b-ca+c-ab>0$.

Comment: @Gina I will give it a try. Thanks! And here is what I just got from a user (who created this problem) : http://emc.mnm.hr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/EMC-2013-Junior-Category-Solutions.pdf

Comment: @Gina,it is not true. you don't know $a-bc>0$.

Comment: this proof is not correct. $a=2,b=c=0.8$ is a counter example.

Comment: @chenbai: ah thanks for pointing that out, I missed that. I guess the more complicated solution is the only one we got then.